# Does Bloch want to "devour" the anti utopian nothing of death, and if so how?

Tags: death, objectivity, hope

Does Bloch want to "devour" the anti utopian nothing of death, and if so how?

> images of hope against death are gathered, against this hardest
> counterblow to utopia; death is therefore its unforgettable awakener.
> It is especially a circulation of that Nothing which is devoured into
> being by the utopian pull; there is no becoming and no victory into
> which the annihilation of what is bad is not actively devoured. All
> the glad tidings which constitute the imagination of religion
> culminate mythically, against death and fate

The introduction to his [Principle of Hope](https://www.marxists.org/archive/bloch/hope/introduction.htm). I assume, from the introduction, yes, and that it involves the fulfilment of the past in the future and clarifying hope etc.. But in what sense is death then not Nothing?

How can death not destroy hope as the will "to be truly present"?

> Expectation, hope, intention towards possibility that has still not
> become: this is not only a basic feature of human consciousness, but,
> concretely corrected and grasped, a basic determination within
> objective reality as a whole.

Is this why, and if so how convincing are his claims that "objective reality as a whole" involves hope?